# Deploy simple images using MDT internal sata drives

Tags: deployment, mdt

Here is a little background into my situation hopefully there is a better way to do it.  A task I perform very frequently is duplicate customers images from their internal sata drives to multiple drives for deployment.  The way I do it now is with a 5 dock sled that has a source drive (with the simple customer image) and 4 blank target disks (drives that I want to copy the image onto).  As you can imagine, this is very time consuming. 
I am familiar with using MDT to deploy images to different servers and workstations and dont have any issues there.  What I would like to know is whether or not I can use MDT to take place of this sled. If we could keep the customers images on the server and then whenever we need to image a drive we could plug it right in with a sata/usb adaptor and just copy it over.  Is this possible?

Comment: You should google that https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d837d88-6d8e-420c-b68f-a5b4baeb5248.aspx

Comment: @adjit No wds won't help here, you should read the article you want someone else to "google" and understand the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could.  You would need a TS that would allow you to select the image required. The difference is you would have to have a full PC- not just the drive, however the scale of deployments is no longer limited to the number of slots in a sled (just the number of power outlets and network connections.

Comment: Thank you for that information. We will have a terminal set up to do this. Are you aware of any additional steps within the MDT UI that I would need to take given the circumstances? Or maybe there are steps I should avoid? I've tried to do research on this specific way to copy images but there isnt much out there.